# What are all of the Chinese phrases in Firefly/Serenity?

Tags: translation, firefly, serenity

Throughout the 14th episode of Firefly and the following movie there are many Chinese phrases strewn about.

What are all of the Chinese phrases in Firefly/Serenity?

Comment: I've watched *Firefly* with subtitles, and it just says something like "[Chinese]" for those parts.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like someone else thought about this and created a [website](http://fireflychinese.kevinsullivansite.net/title/index.html).

There should be a translation for all the phrases used in Firefly. You can search by title or by phrase.

> Chinese translations with standard **Hanyu Pinyin** romanization and Chinese characters for **Firefly** the TV series and **Serenity** the movie and comic books

Enjoy!

Comment: Awesome reference there, but the URL has changed slightly: http://fireflychinese.kevinsullivansite.net/title/index.html

Comment: Being only a link, I'm not sure this qualifies as an answer. Can you transcribe / summarise it?

Comment: So apparently, this worked just fine for 4 years, and now I start to get downvotes because it's one line? What context is to be added? There's a web site with all translations, period.

Comment: Just attempting to put forward the (likely) opinion of the downvoter.  Essentially, link-only answers are not really considered to be good here - and are often downvoted or even deleted.  That said, unless you're willing to enhance your answer with some or all of the phrases, I'd rather a link only answer than none at all.

Comment: @iandotkelly if the op refuses to elaborate, we could CW it and someone else could do the work. As is, this is not an answer and is likely preventing people from writing better answers.

Comment: @Catija ... there's nothing stopping someone else writing a better answer, even one based on the same content.

Comment: @iandotkelly: ...except the copyright of the original website's author, one Kevin Sullivan. Better get his OK before just ripping off his work.